# How should I remove this logic from my view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails app with events, and when an event's end date has passed I want to include an element on `event#show` pages indicating that the event is expired.

Right now I have this logic in my `view` like this:

```
<% if @event.end_time <= Time.now %>
  <h4 class="label--warning">This event has already happened</h4>
<% end %>
```

I understand it's good to strip logic out of views and I don't want to hit the database from the view, so I'm wondering what the best way to do that would be for a case like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are loading the page for an `@event` you have already hit the database. So that code in your view will not generate an extra database query.

The logic in your view (whether or not an event is expired) can be moved to the model. But you're still going to have some code in the view. The nice thing about moving it to the model, however, is that you can easily write tests for the model class.

Model:

```
def is_expired?
  end_time <= Time.now
end
```

View:

```
<% if @event.is_expired? %>
  <h4 class="label--warning">This event has already happened</h4>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Okay, this seems better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having conditional logic in the view you could always use view helpers.

=> app/helpers/expired_event.rb

```
Module ExpiredEvent
    def event_expired?(event)
        if event.end_time <= Time.now
            return "<h4 class="label--warning">This event has already happened</h4>".html_safe
        end
    end
end
```

then in your view

```
<%= event_expired?(@event) %>
```

Something like that?